# "Hello World" Express does not show - I am shown my files instead

Tags: javascript, express, backend

I am trying to build my first app. It's a calculator that measures the level of caffeine in your blood.
I copied the code from : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html (copied below), but it is not showing a page with the words "Hello World!".
Instead, I see 2 links to my 2 files within my folder "CaffeineCalc" (calculator.js + json file). I have copied below the page it shows me. [what my browser page shows instead of Hello World][1]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5500;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
 });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Let me know if you understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6bnv.png

Comment: How are you fetching this request and displaying on the page?

Comment:  lemme guess you started a live-server instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From The Picture you provide, it looks like a `live-server` running and not your NODE application

So To Fix That You Need to open the path of that dir in any terminal or command prompt and run

```
$ npm install
```

***cause I can't see any node_module folder***

then

```
$ node index.js
```

to start the node server

You can now open Your Browser to

`http://localhost:5000`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I realize that my terminal is saying that it cannot find the module so that might be the problem. I thought I had downloaded Express but I will try again.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use express urlencoded.

```
const express = require('express');
    const {
      urlencoded
    } = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }))
app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```